# Can't install application

Tags: wubi

When I try to install any version of Wubi,appears message which asks  me to Burn DVD E. And no choice to change it,or reject.
Regards,
M.Shahbazov

Comment: Wubi has been [deprecated](/q/448686/175814) for years and doesn't work with Windows 8+ in UEFI mode. Please [install Ubuntu as a stand-lone OS alongside Windows](/q/221835/175814)!

Answer (score 1):

The best is to not install Wubi, but to do a proper dual-boot install (if you want to keep Windows).

Please follow this documentation:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Hope it help, if not please answer back.